# Copy class to an existing class C++

Tags: c++, class, copy

How would I copy the `new_grid` to the already existing `this->grid`? I dont quite understand how to do it safely so that when the destructor is called on new_grid it wont cause an issue. The preface of the problem is I need to resize a grid but place the original smaller grid into the new bigger one.

```
void Grid::resize(int new_width, int new_height){
    Grid *new_grid = new Grid(new_width,new_height);
    int x_padding = width - this->width;
    int size = this->width * this->height;
    int multiplier = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
            if (this->get(i,j) == Cell::ALIVE){
                new_grid->set(i+(x_padding * multiplier), j, Cell::ALIVE);
            }
        }
        multiplier++;
    }
    // Need to copy here
}
```

I know there are some issues with negative sizes or a grid being smaller than the origional or the same size. That is not the concern at the moment, I know how to fix those errors.

Comment: You need to implement a copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor and move assignment operator. Those (together with the destructor) are all five in [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: You're fine because `new_grid` will never be destroyed here, it's just leaked ;)

Comment: Without knowing the class members it is hard to say what you need to copy and how.

Comment: Your `Grid` likely has an underlying data structure (a `std::vector` maybe?) that is not another `Grid`. That's the think you need to resize.